# Why is a scope's $$watchers length not equal to the scope's $$watchersCount

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is the difference between a scope's $$watchers field and $$watchersCount? Why are they not always the same?

On the angularjs.org homepage, running `angular.element('body').scope()` in Chrome's developer tools, it's possible to see:

```
$$watchers: Array[3]
$$watchersCount: 80
```

What is the connection between these two fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**$$watchers**: Represent number of `$$watchers` array's length on current scope.

Where as

**$$watchersCount**: Number watchers present on current scope node & its descendants scope $$watchers array.length

Comment: Can you please help me with this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559821/how-to-generate-properties-of-array-with-some-default-value-while-doing-ng-repea